# Generating more than one apk , with same resources , with different app names , using Gradle

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-eclipse

I'm just getting my first steps using Gradle on android projects,just can i know if it's possible to generate two apk with different app names , and SAME resources ,using gradle.
to concreticize more : i want to compile a Helloworld project , and generate 2 apk with different names. is it possible and how ?

thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the product Flavors mechanism.

You'll write:

```
android {
  productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
      packageName "com.my.package.name.1"
    }
    flavor2 {
      packageName "com.my.package.name.2"
    }
  }
}
```

With all your sources in the default source folder (`src/main/java`) and the default manifest (`src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`), you'll automatically get 2 apps which only differ in the package name in their manifest.

Documentation: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants

Comment: well ,that resolved my problems ,the documentation was so helpful,i created two different small apps : free and paid version, i used also this tutorial , and that helped me alot                                                  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JDEK4wkN5I